# jwt refresh token react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I'm working on a small app that utilises JWT for authentication but I'm not sure how to refresh the token when it expires. My token expires after 15 mins, I've provided the details below about my api and how I'm using it. I have a login which generates an `access_token` which will expire eventually and my data will disappear. how do I refresh the token?

Heres what I have tried:

On Login I've added the `refresh token` and the `access_token` to locale storage. If you post a refresh token to the `https://freddy.codesubmit.io/refresh` api it returns an `access_token`; but this hasn't worked.

```
const refreshToken = getItem('refresh_token')

useEffect(() => {
if(response === null) {
  axios.post('https://freddy.codesubmit.io/refresh', {}, {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${refreshToken}`}})
   .then(res => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.access_token);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
}
```

details on jwt api:

```
Retrieve the necessary data for the dashboard at 'https://freddy.codesubmit.io/dashboard'. 
This endpoint requires a 'Authorization: Bearer access_token' header. 
Use the access token that you retrieved from Login. 
Keep in mind that access tokens expire after 15 minutes. 
You may request a fresh access token by sending a POST request to https://freddy.codesubmit.io/refresh' 
with the 'Authorization: Bearer refresh_token' header.
```

I haven't done the refresh token part yet as I'm not sure how to, I assume that may be the problem? Its timing out because the token is expired?

Here is my login:

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';
import { AuthContext } from '../hooks/UserContext';
import Logo from '../images/Freddys_Logo.svg';
import '../css/Login.css';
  
const Login = () => {
  const [userError, setUserError] = useState("");
  const [passError, setPassError] = useState("");
  const {setLoggedIn} = useContext(AuthContext);
  let history = useHistory();
  const [authInfo, setAuthInfo] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: ""
  })

  const handleChange = e => {
    setAuthInfo({
      ...authInfo,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('https://freddy.codesubmit.io/login', authInfo)
      .then(res => {
        setLoggedIn(true);
         localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.access_token);
         localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", res.data.refresh_token);
         history.push('/dashboard')
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

 return (
  <div className="wrapper">
    <div className="logoContainer">
    <div className="heading">
       <p>
         Freddy's
         <br/>
        Artisanal
        <br/>
        Halloween
        <br/>
        Candy Shop
       </p>
    </div>
      <div className="svgLogo">
        <img src={Logo} className="svgLogo" alt="image" />  
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="inputContainer">
    <form method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input 
        name="username" 
        type="text" 
        value={authInfo.username} 
        placeholder="username" 
        onChange={handleChange} 
        className="input" 
      />
      <input 
        name="password" 
        type="password" 
        value={authInfo.password} 
        placeholder="************" 
        onChange={handleChange}  
        className="input" 
      />
      <input 
        type="submit"  
        value="Login" 
        className="submitButton"
      />
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 )
}

export default Login;
```

Here is my api I'm using to grab my data: useFetch.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const useFetch = async => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          "https://freddy.codesubmit.io/dashboard"
        , {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}});

        setResponse(res);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error, "err");
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [token]);
  return { response, error };
};
export default useFetch;
```

Here is the page I'm trying to display my data on: Dashboard.jsx

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import Layout from './Layout';
import Table from './Table';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthContext } from '../hooks/UserContext'
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";
import Switch from "react-switch";
import BarChart from 'react-bar-chart';

import '../css/Dashboard.css'

const Dashboard = () => {
  const {} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { response, error } = useFetch();
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token")


  const handleCheckedChange = () => {
    setChecked(!checked)
  }

  const lastSevenDays = [
    {text: 'yesterday', value: 500}, 
    {text: 'today', value: 1300},
    {text: 'day 3', value: 300},
    {text: 'day 4', value: 300}, 
    {text: 'day 5', value: 300},
    {text: 'day 6', value: 300}, 
    {text: 'day 7', value: 300}, 
  ];
  const lastTwelveMonths = [
    {text: 'this month', value: 500}, 
    {text: 'today', value: 1300},
    {text: 'day 3', value: 300},
    {text: 'day 4', value: 300}, 
    {text: 'day 5', value: 300},
    {text: 'day 6', value: 300}, 
    {text: 'day 7', value: 300}, 
  ];
  const margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};

  console.log(error)

 return (
    <Layout>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="item">
            <span className="textStyle">Today</span>
            <p>$1456 / 9 orders</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <span className="textStyle">Today</span>
            <p>$1456 / 9 orders</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <span className="textStyle">Today</span>
            <p>$1456 / 9 orders</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="revenueContainer">
          <div className="title">
          {!checked ? <h2>Revenue (last 7 days)</h2> : <h2>Revenue (last 12 months)</h2>}
          </div>
          <div className="toggle">
            <Switch 
              onChange={handleCheckedChange} 
              checked={checked} 
              onColor="#86d3ff"
              onHandleColor="#2693e6"
              uncheckedIcon={false}
              checkedIcon={true}
              boxShadow="0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)"
              activeBoxShadow="0px 0px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div style={{width: '100%'}}> 
            {!checked ? (
              <BarChart 
                ylabel=''
                width={600}
                height={300}
                margin={margin}
                data={lastSevenDays}
              />
              ) : !!checked ? (
                <BarChart 
                ylabel=''
                width={600}
                height={300}
                margin={margin}
                data={lastTwelveMonths}
              />
              ) : null}
            </div>
          </div>

        <h2>Bestsellers</h2>
        <Table bestsellers={response?.data.dashboard.bestsellers} /> 
    </Layout>
 )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Table component in Dashboard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/Table.css';

const Table = ({bestsellers}) => {
  if(bestsellers === undefined || null) {
    return <div> loading...</div>
  }
  return (
    <div className="tableContainer">
      <div className="headingContainer">
        <div className="tableHeader"><span className="tableHeading">Product Name</span></div>
          <div className="tableHeader"><span className="tableHeading">Price</span></div>
          <div className="tableHeader"><span className="tableHeading"># Units Sold</span></div>
          <div className="tableHeader"><span className="tableHeading">Revenue</span></div>
      </div>
      {bestsellers
         .slice(0, 3)
         .map(row => (
        <div className="rowContainer" key={row.product.id}> 
          <div className="tableItem">
            <span className="tableItemText">{row.product.name}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="tableItem">
            <span className="tableItemText">N/A</span>
          </div>
          <div className="tableItem">
            <span className="tableItemText">{row.units}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="tableItem">
            <span className="tableItemText">{row.revenue}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: Whats `res.data.refresh_token` for if not a refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

Just set a timeout of less than 15 minutes, at the moment of authorization, with a callback of sending a request with a refresh token. Then, after getting the fresh one, swap the auth_tokens.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to put what I tried in the question, I've updated the question

Comment: It's hard to interpret. There are many namespaces we don't know: variables, functions.. But the idea I've already sketched out: you want to get the refresh token only before the original token's expiration (and not from a `useEffect` without any dependency, that will send a request on every user interaction!!!).